# Windows Phone 8.1 C# .net Exchange Web Services

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, .net-4.5, office365

I'm wondering if anyone knows the best way to connect to EWS using C#.net on Windows Phone 8.1? I need mailbox and contacts access and I can't figure out how to go about this.

I'm using 4.5 Framework for the application if this helps?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Office 365 API Tools in Visual Studio](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7e947621-ef93-4de7-93d3-d796c43ba34f).  Install this extension and right-click your project in Solution Explorer -> Add -> Connected Service.  Choose "Office 365 APIs" on the left and pick "Mail" and "Contacts" in the middle.

There is also [a blog](http://blogs.office.com/2014/08/05/office-365-api-tool-visual-studio-2013-summer-update/) describing the tool.

Answer (score 0):

[Exchange Web Services .NET](http://www.independentsoft.de/exchangewebservices) has portable class library version. It helps you to build cross-platform apps with EWS support.